# GameCenter authentication compatibility issue in iOS 4, 5, and 6

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios6, game-center

currently I'm in the stage where I'll be integrating GameCenter into my games.

I saw these 2 authentication methods in the documentation

- authenticateHandler
- authenticateWithCompletionHandler: (Deprecated in iOS 6.0)

My question is, which one should I use?
Because my games will be supported by the minimum iOS which is 4.3 and up until 6.0

If I use **authenticateWithCompletionHandler:** , it says will be deprecated in iOS 6.0
If I use **authenticateHandler** *property*, I wonder does iOS 4.x and 5.x able to run it?

Hope someone can explain to me, I'm confused by the compatibility now :(

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is safe to use deprecated methods if you want to support older devices or iOS versions. It does not mean that the function is removed anytime soon... It's just a hint that a better or newer version of the function is available.

If the new function offers something the old don't, you could check if the function is available at runtime (`respondsToSelector`) and if not use the old one.